# Simple but Tricky sqlite search query for

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite, plpgsql

I have following sqlite query for finding words which contain character 'w'

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE supplier_name like '%w%';
```

**which works fine for words like: awesome,overflow etc**

**But My Database contains word like: αγαπάω , αγαπώ etc**

I want these words also get selected when i fired that query but some how its not working i think these are accents words but anyhow i want to solve it
so will u please help me to get over that issue

Comment: The letter in question is a lower case Greek omega.  I wouldn't expect a search on a Latin "w" to pick it up.

Comment: If this is a sqllite question, why is it tagged for MySQL, Oracle, and plpgsql which is the procedural language for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

the letter "ω" is a greek alphabet letter, named omega, which has no connection at all with the letter "w", only the shape.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below example.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
     SELECT StringValue = N'Record1 Data: a'  UNION 
     SELECT StringValue = N'Record2 Data: b'  UNION 
     SELECT StringValue = N'Record3 Data: ω'  UNION -- (omega character)
     SELECT StringValue = N'Record4 Data: w'  
 ) 

 SELECT *
 FROM CTE
 WHERE StringValue LIKE N'%[wω]%'
```

Record 3 and 4 will be returned.

Remember to add the N character before the single quote.